# Date picker don't show proper date

Tags: iphone

i am new to iPhone application development. i am creating simple application with using of datepicker. i have a date picker and a button. simply i want to print selected date and time when i click on button. bellow is my code.

```
- (IBAction)showSelectedDate:(id)sender {    
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDate *pickerDate = [m_datePicker date];

    NSLog(@"%@", pickerDate); 
}
```

In log date is print but it is wrong. i am select "2012-03-28 03:26 PM" this date from picker and in log i get the date "2012-03-28 09:50".

Thanks in adv....

Comment: [m_datePicker date]; This 'm_datepicker' belongs to which class??, coz the 'date' it returns is being displayed in your log.!

Comment: The apple document says that "The default is the date when the UIDatePicker object is created." So I think you are getting the default date.

Comment: check out the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272953/uidatepicker-strange-behaviour-not-setting-date-and-wrong-date-being-selected][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272953/uidatepicker-strange-behaviour-not-setting-date-and-wrong-date-being-selected

Answer (score 1):

Try this code... It may work fine for you.

```
- (IBAction)showSelectedDate:(id)sender
{
        NSDate *selectedDate = myPicker.date;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY"];


    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
    NSLog(@" %@",selectedDate);
}
```

If u want time replace

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY"];
```

with this line

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"day, MMM HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this code print only date. but i don't have problem with date. i am having a problem with time. see my original post on upside.

Comment: [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
This is work for me...but when i going to convert string to date it's show wrong again.

Comment: please post your code.So that i can check where you making mistake.

Comment: - (IBAction)showSelectedDate:(id)sender {    
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDate *pickerDate = [m_datePicker date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSString *str = [formatter2 stringFromDate:pickerDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);

Comment: NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter3 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    [formatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSDate *finalDate = [formatter3 dateFromString:str];
    NSLog(@"%@",finalDate); 
}

Comment: Man learn how to Add comment and how to add code.Check stak overflow guidelines.

Comment: `NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];`
    `[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];`
    `NSDate *str = (NSDate *)[formatter2 stringFromDate:pickerDate];`
    `NSLog(@"%@", str);`
    
    `NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];`
    `[formatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];`
    `[formatter3 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];`
    `NSDate *finalDate = [formatter3 dateFromString:str];`
    `NSLog(@"%@",finalDate);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using GMT rather than local time so that it just looks wrong. Use

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

Comment: @BhavinMakadia: did you set your picker's timezone ?