# UIDatePicker appears disabled when setting time programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker set for **UIDatePickerModeTime**.  I am using the following code to set the time in my datePicker:

```
[self.oTimePicker setDate:dateFromString(self.oStartTime.text, @"HH:mm")];
[self.oTimePicker reloadInputViews];
```

which works but then the datePicker appears gray in color (see image below; it appears the datePicker is disabled), and sets the time to 06:00, no matter what is selected.   Here is an image of the results; notice that I have picked 1:30 PM, but the text box shows 06:00;  in addition, no matter what I select, nothing changes (the time displays what I pick (here 1:30 PM), but the value in the datePicker remains at 14:00 (but doesn't show 14:00 verified with NSLog), no matter what I select.  Any ideas of what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Probably very obvious but have you got user interaction enabled on the date picker? - Just tested not going to be this.

Comment: I think maybe the time you are setting from the string is causing issues with the UIDatePicker - check this by setting the date correctly using this: NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd"];;
NSDate *anyDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2019-09-11"];   
[datePicker setDate:anyDate];

[dateFormat release];

Comment: John... it's not the "date"... it's the "time"... and my code is above.  SD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are having a time-zone issue with `UIDatePicker`. That is why it is showing one time in a `UIDatePicker` and another in your label (Washington has -7 time difference). There are lot of questions and answers about this topic (one example: [iphone UIDatePicker showing wrong date in Central Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571036/iphone-uidatepicker-showing-wrong-date-in-central-timezone)).

Another problem you are having is that UIDatePicker becomes disabled. This issue can be caused if you are setting `datePicker.minimumDate` to current date and using `UIDatePickerModeTime`.

Comment: Got it!  I had both the minimum and maximum dates checked in IB... removed that and it works like a champ!  Thank you so much for your help... I truly appreciate it!